# PHP $_GET variable is empty due to URL rewriting

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have rewritten a URL with .htaccess so that it looks prettier.
But when I add a query string to this URL, the keys and are not visible from PHP.

In my .htaccess file, I tried several things to fix the problem, but nothing worked.

```
RewriteEngine On
[some code]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ ?site=$1
```

I have tried this rewriting, to see if it works:

```
RewriteRule ^search?q=g ?site=search&q=g
```

But if I `print_r($_GET)` in PHP, I will just get `Array ( [site] => search )`
Try it on http://kwtsports.bplaced.de/search?q=g.

I have a search field that redirects to `/search?q=blablaSearchQuery`, but as I said, `$_GET['q']` is empty.

This also doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^search?q=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ ?site=search&q=$1
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `[QSA]` to the end of your `RewriteRule`. This appends the old query string to the result.

See the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know, why this happens?

Yes. You cannot test the query string in the rewrite rule, so this part of your rule will never work: `RewriteRule ^search?q=g`.

If you want to test a query string, you have to test it in the rewrite cond.

For example, for your `RewriteRule ^search?q=g?site=search&q=g` example, you would have to do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^search/?$ site=search&q=%1 [L]
```

In this particular case, since you are not wanting to change the `q` value, we don't really need to test it, and you could simply pass it through with the `QSA` option after adding `site=search`:

```
RewriteRule ^search/?$ site=search [L,QSA]
```